# Compare/View 2 rows of images via scroll or slider

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, slider

My goal is to have an interface where two **rows/columns** of images are compared.

[image: In the image I linked to, you can see there will be 2 rows of images that are being compared.]

I'd like to slide/scroll through each row so that the user can eventually identify 2 images that match.

I've seen code for a few sliders and scroll apps, but not any where each row can slide independent of the other. Any advice or links to resources online would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check this out [Codrops](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/05/26/product-comparison-layout-effect/)

Comment: Hi Momin! Do you know of a responsive layout where it's only 2 rows of images being compared? Or 1 row with a static image and the row adjacent has a slider? Basically Row A finds a match in Row B by sliding through Row B. Thanks for the link.

Comment: This one only I had to know.... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery-ui there are a number of tools on there for things like sliders, and each element can be put on there separately.  I'd be amazed if you can do the same with images, although mostly I've seen it done using vertical sliders and it sounds like you want horizontal ones.

Comment: Hi Sibaz. Thanks for the quick response!! Basically I want the 2 images to take up the entire mobile screen. For horizontal vs vertical, I just imagined a mobile device vertical so the user would be scrolling horizontally, but of course if they use their device horizontally, I'd want the app to respond by sliding vertically. I'm such a newbie with all of this :) I will def check out jquery-ui!! thanks again.

Comment: Hmmm, I was thinking desktop rather than mobile, but I suspect it's all html5, so do look at jquery-ui, that's my go-to place for js ui tools